# Update <head> balise on Jquery/Ajax navigation Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing an ajax navigation for a wordpress website. I update the `#content` with fade, this is ok, but I want to just update my head with my new page head, I don't find!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //hash change
    $(window).hashchange(function () {

        //on retrouve le vrai lien
        var arg = window.location.hash.substring(3);
        var link = 'http://ladresse.graphsynergie.com/' + arg;


        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            processData: true,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                data = innerShiv(data, false);
                var contenu = $(data).find("#contenu");

                //problem part
                var head = $(data).find('head').text();
                document.head = head;
                //problem part end


                $('#contenu').fadeOut('200', function () {
                    $(this).html(contenu.html()).fadeIn('200');
                });
            }
        });
    });
    //end

    //détection d'un hash onload
    if (window.location.hash.substring(3) != '') {
        $(window).trigger('hashchange');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in consideration that .text() will only retrieve the "text" contained inside the html tags, review the [jQuery documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/text/) I think that what you actually want [is to use the .html() method](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

So, I think that you may want to replace those 2 problematic lines of code with this:

```
$("head").html($(data).find("head").html());
```

**Update**:

Apparently all browsers strip out anything that it's not inside the "body" when they create the DOM object. The thing is that when you do: "$(data)" jQuery creates a DOM object with the content of the "data" variable, and your browser decides to ignore all the elements that are not inside the "body" tag, therefore in the internal DOM object that jQuery handles the "head" element is not there anymore. So you will have to find a workaround.

Try this, put these lines of code just after the line "success: function (data) {":

```
var headIni = data.toLowerCase().indexOf("<head");
var headEnd = data.toLowerCase().indexOf("</head>");
headIni = data.indexOf(">", headIni + 1) + 1;
var headHTML = data.substring(headIni, headEnd);
```

And then, replace the line that I initially suggested for this one:

> $("head").html(headHTML);

This should do the job. I'm sure that there must be more elegant ways to do it, but hopefully this will be good enough for you.

**Update 2:**

If you follow [this link](https://gist.github.com/742952) you will find a much better way to do it. Just add the library "jquery.ba-htmldoc.js" that you will find there, and then do this:

```
$("head").html($.htmlDoc(data).find('head').html());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! This change my head, but $(data).find("head").html() return nothing, so, my new head is empty after this... lol

Comment: Amazing ! Thanks a lot for your explain and for searching. Really cool to have an ajax navigation with head update

//Thx to Josep will be add to, I think with this line, my script will work faster :p

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite the content of your "< head >" tag use

```
$("head").html('NEW STUFF IN HEAD');
```

Comment: thank's, first part is solve, I can change my head ! but I don't find to have my new head, to select <head> part of $(data). Maybe you have some tips for this ?... :)